# Windows Phone 8 emulator working but device fails to connect to server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services, windows-phone-8, device

I have successfully connected the emulator to my service by opening a connection, allowing the port in firewall, and everything that this article tells me to do: http://blog.anthonybaker.me/2013/06/how-to-connect-to-local-web-services.html. The problem is that it doesn't work when I load the app onto an actual device. In the article it states that to test if the connection works, type in the IP Address and port number into the web browser of either the emulator or the device:

```
http://IPaddress:portnumber/
```

When I do this on the emulator it does what I want it to do, but when I do this on the device, the web browser tells me it could not find the address. Any idea what is going on here?

Comment: Did you try check with fiddler? It can help understand what happens .

Comment: When I use fiddler, and search for the site on the emulator, fiddler shows that it connected. When I use the actual device to do the same thing though, nothing appears on fiddler.

Comment: Hmmmmmmmm ......it's looks like you don't send request. Check in settings of application which connection application use - maybe application use ONLY wi-fi and u send from cellular or something like that.